# How to recover from pytroch CUDA out of memory?

Tags: pytorch

I tried the following code. When the code in `try` failed because of out of CUDA memory, I reduced the batch size to a half in `except` but it still appear the same issue for running the model in `except` but I'm sure half of the batch size is runnable since I have tried to directly run the code in `except` without trying the full batch. It works fine. By the way, is there any way to automatically set the batch size to fully use the CUDA memory without overflow?

```
try:
    output = model(Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(x))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(pos))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(m))).to(device))
    loss = criterion(output, Variable(torch.LongTensor(y)).to(device))#lb.transform(y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    losses.append(loss.data.mean())
except:
    half = int(len(x) / 2)
    x1 = x[:half]
    x2 = x[half:]
    pos1 = pos[:half]
    pos2 = pos[half:]
    m1 = m[:half]
    m2 = m[half:]
    y1 = y[:half]
    y2 = y[half:]
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(x1))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(pos1))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(m1))).to(device))
    loss = criterion(output, Variable(torch.LongTensor(y1)).to(device))#lb.transform(y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    losses.append(loss.data.mean())
    output = model(Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(x2))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(pos2))).to(device),Variable(torch.LongTensor(np.array(m2))).to(device))
    loss = criterion(output, Variable(torch.LongTensor(y2)).to(device))#lb.transform(y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    losses.append(loss.data.mean())
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is still something left on your gpu. Did you try to free your cuda cache using torch.cuda.empty_cache() in the beginning of except?